# how to solve slideshow css problem?

Tags: html, css

My Css

```
#container{
    display:block;
}

#container ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:block;
}

#container li{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#container img{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

my HTML

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
<li><img src="1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

all the pictures rendered under each other which is what I want but the problem is that if I add any div after #container it will inserted behind it, I want to insert some divs after it but every time I add another div it goes behind it, how can i solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by setting the height and width on `#container ul`. That is what I've done when making a photo rotator, since the image sizes are usually known ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clearfix the div you insert after container :

```
<div id="container">
</div>

<div id="mydiv" class="clearfix">
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.clearfix {
   clear:both;
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: How does this fix the problem in the OP if there is no float?

Answer (score 0):

Change the style for #container_li to (i.e. remove the absolute positioning).

```
#container li
{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: -4px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Maybe you should also alter #container ul to (remove relative positioning)

```
#container ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:block;
}
```

Offset of `-4px` works for IE, `-5px` for Firefox.

Comment: i want that absolute so all the images rendered under each other

Comment: Well using you original style all images are placed on top of each other. Tested with IE 8 and Firefox 3.6

Comment: Added an negative top margin of -4px, so that the images align correctly.